# BBB: `bbb-conf --check` showing IP addresses as `inet` - ifconfig woes

Tags: debian, ifconfig

Upon the install of [BigBlueBotton](http://bigbluebutton.org) in Debian 9, I run the script `bbb-conf --check` to make consistency checks of the setup.  ([bbb-conf](http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/install/bbb-conf.html) is a configuration/setup tool to BBB)

The script return me in all consistency checks the address of the machine as `inet`. What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out why `bbb-conf` is not seeing the IP address correctly.

[bbb-conf](https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/blob/master/bigbluebutton-config/bin/bbb-conf) is a `bash` script that runs the `ifconfig` command.

The cause is that the output/fields of the `ifconfig` output changed in Debian version 9.

Thus, the regexps in the script no longer give a match to the current address.

In Debian 8/Jessie:

`inet addr:193.136.188.36  Bcast:193.136.188.255  Mask:255.255.255.0`

In Debian 9/Stretch:

`inet 10.23.20.19  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.23.20.255`

Is it recommend to change the script to `ip addr show` as `ifconfig` is being deprecated, and the output of `ip` does not change across versions.

So instead of:

```
ifconfig | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | grep -E "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*" | tail -1 | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'
```

change it to:

```
ip addr show | grep inet | tail -1 | awk ' { print $2 } '
```

After changing/correcting the offending lines, the script already shows the IP address correctly, however now it spews as warnings, that the IP addresses in the configuration files are incorrect. The post-installation scripts also inserts `inet` instead of the correct address due to unfortunate changes to the ifconfig output format in Debian.