# How to capture the first IP address from a ifconfig command?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, ifconfig

How to capture the first IP address that comes from `ifconfig` command?

```
ifconfig -a
enw178032: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 100.14.22.12  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 100.14.255.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe9c:158a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:10:56:9c:65:8a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 26846250  bytes 12068811576 (11.2 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 58671  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3368855  bytes 1139160934 (1.0 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Expected result:

```
IP=100.14.22.12
```

Comment: The question has been answered, either using awk or grep / cut, etc. But it's still a bad idea in general to use and grep from ifconfig. ip is better suited and better supported in modern Linux builds.

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem.  What information do you really want?  The main network-facing IP address of the machine?  Any network-facing IP address of the machine?  The IP address of the first network adapter?  Any IP address, doesn't matter what it is?  There is probably a more direct, accurate, and portable way to get the information you need.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is better avoid using `ifconfig` for getting an IP address in a scriptas it is deprecated in some distributions (e.g. CentOS and others, do not install it by default anymore).

In others systems, the output of ifconfig varies according to the release of the distribution (e.g. the output/spacing/fields of `ifconfig` differs from Debian 8 to Debian 9, for instance).

For getting the IP address with `ip`, in a similar way you are asking:

```
ip addr | awk ' !/127.0.0.1/ && /inet/ { gsub(/\/.*/, "", $2); print "IP="$2 } '
```

Or better yet:

```
$ ip -o -4  address show  | awk ' NR==2 { gsub(/\/.*/, "", $4); print $4 } '
192.168.1.249
```

Or, as you ask "IP="

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "IP="
ip -o -4  address show  | awk ' NR==2 { gsub(/\/.*/, "", $4); print $4 } '
```

Adapting shamelessly the idea from @Roman

```
$ ip -o -4  address show  | awk ' NR==2 { gsub(/\/.*/, "", $4); print "IP="$4 } ' 
IP=192.168.1.249
```

Normal output:

```
 $ ip -o -4  address show 
1: lo    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0    inet 192.168.1.249/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

From `man ip`:

> -o, -oneline
>                 output each record on a single line, replacing line feeds with
>                 the '\' character. This is convenient when you want to count
>                 records with wc(1) or to grep(1) the output.

See one example of why `ifconfig` is not advised: [BBB: `bbb-conf --check` showing IP addresses as `inet` - ifconfig woes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329176/bbb-bbb-conf-check-showing-ip-addresses-as-inet-ifconfig-woes/329177)

For understanding why `ifconfig` is on the way out, see [Difference between 'ifconfig' and 'ip' commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93412/difference-between-ifconfig-and-ip-commands)

> `ifconfig` is from net-tools, which hasn't been able to fully keep up
>   with the Linux network stack for a long time. It also still uses ioctl
>   for network configuration, which is an ugly and less powerful way of
>   interacting with the kernel.
>
> Around 2005 a new mechanism for controlling the network stack was
>   introduced - netlink sockets.
>
> To configure the network interface `iproute2` makes use of that
>   full-duplex netlink socket mechanism, while `ifconfig` relies on an
>   ioctl system call.

Comment: I prefer not to set  eth0 as default because this name changing on machines  , can we provide flexible syntax

Comment: @yael Changed, took out eth0. However Roman did better than me printing the "IP=" inside `awk`. Too much brainpower for me, still waking up. Avoid `ifconfig`, it has not future, and the position of IP address changes, there are at least two different versions/implementations(?) for Linux out there that I know off.

Comment: Just for info, on _newer_ versions of iproute2 (eg: not on CentOS7 nor Debian8) ip can take a `-brief` parameter and its output becomes easier to parse (2015-08-31: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/commit/?id=5d295bb8e1af491bc3de1d2506cbb2bd6bbd9da1 )

Comment: @A.B also -o as I use helps, thanks, will check it ou

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about `-o` which indeed seems useful for scripts

Comment: @A.B My bad, added an explanation of `-o` to make it more evident.

Answer (score 6):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
ifconfig -a | awk 'NR==2{ sub(/^[^0-9]*/, "", $2); printf "IP=%s\n", $2; exit }'
```

Sample output:

```
IP=10.0.2.15
```

Answer (score -3):

```
ip addr | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | grep 'inet ' | \
awk {'print $2'} | awk -F "/" {'print "IP="$1'}
```

Comment: see this: `ip addr | awk ' !/127.0.0.1/ && /inet/ { gsub(/\/.*/, "", $2); print "IP="$2 } ' `

Comment: Why are you grepping for the localhost IP 127.0.0.1?